# Searching data from JSON file from TextBox in c#

Tags: c#, json, winforms

This is my json file content

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Shubham",
    "LastName": "Singh",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "EnrollmentDate": "6/01/2019",
    "AssignedCourse": "Python",
    "RollNumber": "SSCou1666",
    "AssignedTeacher": "XYZ",
    "ContactNumber": "100"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Shivang",
    "LastName": "Singh",
    "MiddleName": "Rathod",
    "EnrollmentDate": "7/01/2019",
    "AssignedCourse": "French",
    "RollNumber": "SSCou6479",
    "AssignedTeacher": "ABC",
    "ContactNumber": "600"
  }
]
```

My goal is to search the for specific record by name in textbox in C# winforms. I am not able to understand how to first search for the particular record in JSON against a particular name or Roll Number. Is this even possible in JSON?

Comment: To my knowledge, JSON only offers storage of data and you will have to use something else for query abilities.

Comment: deserialize to a c# object and use lambda query to find.

Answer (score 0):

Using [NewtownSoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), you can deserialize your JSON array in to a `List<object>` and then filter the List using any of the class object Properties.

For example, filter the list using a specific `RollNumber` value:

```
string JSONObject = [Your JSON string]
var allStudents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(JSONObject);

string rollNumberValue = textBox1.Text;

//Filter the list using a property value
var specificStudent = allStudents.FirstOrDefault(s => s.RollNumber == rollNumberValue);
```

The Student class used as container:

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public string AssignedCourse { get; set; }
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTeacher { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```